# Extend formula only to a certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where there is data from `A3-A6`. But this can be dynamic. The number of rows can change. I have formulas written in D3 all the way till `BU3`. I would like to extend these - `Autofill` to `D6` automatically. But if the data is till `A7`, the formula should extend to `A7` as well. The code which i have written is below. The problem is without there being data in `A7` the formula is still getting copied over there. Also there is the next set of data from `A19` which should not be impacted by this formulas. `A6-A19` are blanks

```
Sheets("Working").Select
Set sht = ActiveSheet
Dim LR As Long
                                         
LR = sht.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Range("D3:BU3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:BU" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Sheets("Working").Select
                                         Set sht = ActiveSheet
                                         Dim LR As Long
                                         
                                       LR = sht.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
                                                     Range("D3:BU3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:BU" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault

Comment: You could probably benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248)

Comment: Are A1 and A2 blank or do they have data?

Comment: A1 and A2 are headers

Comment: So, they will be part of the `CurrentRegion` and will therefore be counted in `.Rows.Count`. Are you expecting this?

Comment: No. I do not want these 2 rows to be included. The formulas needs to be copied only from D3 till the last row. And the range for last row should start only from a3 till last row with data until a19. Can this be done? Pls advise

Comment: Are you familiar with [the `Range.End(..)` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end)?

Comment: As @Chronocidal suggested, have you tried `LR = sht.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row`? You must make sure cells below A6 are empty. Sometimes they have invisible characters (e.g. spaces or `""` resulting from a formula). Select the cells below a6 and press DELETE to clear contents and try again. I tested you code as it is and it actually works.

Comment: You also need to cap `LR` after setting its value (e.g. `If LR > 19 Then LR = 19`). This is because if you add data until A19, `End()` and `CurrentRegion` will extend to the end of the next set of data.

Comment: Ok let me re try. Thank you

Comment: Super symmetry - this worked perfectly fine. Will this code also work to define the last row when only one row exists. But I need to keep in case in future we have greater than one row to identify last row?